# Failure/Error: Post#create testing with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to Rspec and testing in general I have this code in `stores_controller_spec.rb` file

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe StoresController, type: :controller do
    let(:vendor) { FactoryBot.create(:vendor) }
    let(:auth_headers) { vendor.create_new_auth_token }
    let(:city) { FactoryBot.create(:city) }
    let(:store) { FactoryBot.create(:store, vendor_id: vendor.id, city_id: city.id) }

    before(:example) do
        request.headers.merge!(auth_headers)
    end

    describe "Post#create" do
        it 'creates a new store' do
            post :create, params: { store: attributes_for(:store) }
            expect(Store.count).to eq(1)
        end
    end
end
```

and `factories/store.rb` file :

```
FactoryBot.define do
    factory :store do
        long Faker::Number.positive
        lat Faker::Number.positive
        store_name Faker::Name.name  
        telephone_number Faker::Number.number(10)
    end
end
```

and `factories/city.rb` file :

```
FactoryBot.define do
    factory :city do
        city_name Faker::Name.name
    end
end
```

and after running the test, I got this :

```
Failures:
    1) StoresController Post#create creates a new store    
    Failure/Error: expect(Store.count).to eq(1)

   expected: 1
        got: 0
```

and `StoresContoller.rb`:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_vendor!

    def create
      @store = Store.new(store_params)
      if @store.save
        render json: @store, status: :created, location: @store
      else
        render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private
      def store_params
        params.require(:store).permit(:vendor_id, :city_id, :store_name, :long, :lat, :telephone_number)
      end
end
```

as should I mention that `Store` `belongs_to :city` and
  `belongs_to :vendor`
and when I test that `expect(store).to be_valid` on the same block after `post :create` line, the test passed!

Could you explain to me what is the wrong thing I did, please ?!

Comment: You will need to paste the controller code for debugging this. My guess would be either some authentication is failing (`auth_headers` above) OR some validation is failing when creating `Store` record.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thanks man, just updated the question, about your guesses: I tested the authentication, it passed and in this test particularly I commented the authentication for vendor, the second one  I tested `expect(store).to be_valid` inside the same block of create, also it passed!

Comment: In your rspec, you can check `response.body` after making call to `create`. If there were some validation errors it will return them.

Comment: I printed `response.body` I got this: `"{\"city\":[\"must exist\"],\"vendor\":[\"must exist\"]}"`
But I made the association when I create store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't need to pass the store attributes under key `params` in the request. Change this line and see if it works:

```
post :create, { store: attributes_for(:store).merge(city_id: city.id, vendor_id: vendor.id) }
```

Also your factory `:store` would not create valid records without following changes:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :store do
    ...
    association :city
    association :vendor
  end
end
```

Comment: Well I tried it yesterday, I got 
`Failure/Error: post :create, { store: attributes_for(:store) }
     
     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: store`

Comment: Can you try again? and post the stack trace if it doesn't work?

Comment: Same old, `Failures:

  1) StoresController Post#create creates a new store
     Failure/Error: post :create, { store: attributes_for(:store) }
     
     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: store
     # ./spec/controllers/stores_controller_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.61 seconds (files took 11.06 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/stores_controller_spec.rb:37 # StoresController Post#create creates a new store`

Comment: Okay, lets try this. Change `let` to `let!` here `let!(:store) { ... }` and see what error it gives.

Comment: Worked like magic!
I remember reading about the lazy and eager instantiation!
But could you edit your answer and explain more!

Comment: Sorry to say, but your test still didn't work. Replacing `let!` with `let` was just to see if the factory was defined correctly. Your test is passing because `let!` created a `Store` object and the count was 1 even before making request to `create` action.

Comment: Really, so what should I do now!

Comment: Could you try `post :create, { store: attributes_for(:store) }` AND removing `let(:store) { ... }` statement completely?

Comment: Please mark the answer unaccepted for now so that other users can also see the question is unanswered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161683/discussion-between-mohammad-eliass-alhusain-and-jagdeep-singh).